# How to create a jasmine unit test when using angular-datatables

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-datatables

I am using angular-datatables in my project and I would like to write a Jasmine/Karma unit test for it.

This is code from my controller:

```
 $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('/api/books/')
                .withBootstrap()
                .withPaginationType('simple_numbers')
                .withDisplayLength(10)
                //.withOption('serverSide', true)
                .withOption('processing', true)
                .withOption('createdRow', createdRow);

            $scope.dtColumns = [
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('name').withTitle('Name')
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Actions').notSortable()
                    .renderWith(actionsHtml)
            ];
```

How can I now write a unit test for it, faking a JSON response from `/api/books` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var $scope, $state, DTColumnBuilder, DTOptionsBuilder, createController, $httpBackend;

beforeEach(function () {
  DTColumnBuilder  = {};
  DTOptionsBuilder = {};
  $state           = {};
  $httpBackend     = {};

  module('app', function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('$state', $state);
    $provide.value('$httpBackend', $httpBackend);
    $provide.value('DTColumnBuilder', DTColumnBuilder);
    $provide.value('DTOptionsBuilder', DTOptionsBuilder);
  });

  inject(function ($controller, $injector) {
    $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
    $state = $injector.get('$state');
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    DTColumnBuilder  = $injector.get('DTColumnBuilder');
    DTOptionsBuilder = $injector.get('DTOptionsBuilder');

    aliasOfYourController = function () {
      return $controller('originalNameOfController', {
        $scope: scope,
        $state: $state,
        DTOptionsBuilder: DTOptionsBuilder,
        DTColumnBuilder: DTColumnBuilder        
      });
    }

    spyOn($state, 'go');

    $httpBackend.flush();
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  // Stub out the methods of interest. 
  DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource = angular.noop;
  DTColumnBuilder.bar = function () { return 'bar'; };
});
```

---

The nature of a `spy` is that of letting the original implementation do its thing, but *recording* all of the calls to said function and an assortment of associated data.

A `stub` on the other hand is a `spy` with an extended API where you can completely modify the workings of said function. Return value, expected parameters, etc etc.

Assuming we used the aforementioned beforeEach block, `DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource` would be a `noop` at this point. As such it would be safe to `spy` on it and expect the method to have been called.

```
it('should have been called', function () {
  var spy = spyOn(DTOPtionsBuilder, 'fromSource');
  aliasOfYourController();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

If you wanted to manipulate the return value of said function, I would grab [sinonjs](http://sinonjs.org) and make it a `stub`.

```
it('became "foo"', function () {
  DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource = sinon.stub().returns('foo');
  aliasOfYourController();
  expect($scope.dtOptions).toEqual('foo');
});
```

Now, since you are working with promises it's a wee bit more complicated but the basics of stubbing out a promise based function would be to:

- Inject `$q` into your spec file.
- Tell the `stub` to return `$q.when(/** value **/)` in the case of a **resolved promise.**
- Tell the `stub` to return `$q.reject(/** err **/)` in the case of a **rejected promise.**
- Run `$timeout.flush()` to flush all deferred tasks. And If you are mocking an http response you use `$httpBackend` in your unit tests and `$httpBackend.flush()` to flush all deferred tasks.
- *Trigger the `done` callback to notify Jasmine that you are done waiting for async tasks (may not be needed). This depends on the test framework/runner.*

It *could* look something like so:

```
it('resolves with "foo"', function (done) {
  DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource = sinon.stub().returns($q.when('foo'));
  expect($scope.options).to.eventually.become('foo').and.notify(done); // this is taken from the chai-as-promised library, I'm not sure what the Jasmine equivalent would be (if there is one).
  aliasOfYourController();
  $timeout.flush();
});
```

And, If you want to test `$state.go('toSomeState')` then unit test case can be :

```
   it('should redirected successfully', function() {
       var stateParams = {
          id: 22,
          name: sample
       }
       functionNameInsideWhichItsBeenCalled(stateParams);
       expect($state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('toSomeState', {
           id: stateParams.id,
           name: stateParams.name
       });
   });
```

Now, a lot of this is just guesswork at this point. It's quite hard to set up a fully working test suite without having the source code running right beside me for cross reference, but I hope this will at least give you some ideas of how to get going with your $httpBackend, spy and stubs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i'll try your suggestions as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

To mock an http response you use $httpBackend in your unit tests.

use $httpBackend.expect when you want the test fail if the request is not made.
You can define a mock response too.

use $httpBackend.when when you want to define a mock response IF a request is made but not making the request mandatory.

CODE TO EXPLAIN ...

CONTROLLER CODE TO TEST

```
self.callme = function() {
    $http.get('/mypath').then(function() {
        console.log("I will be executed when flush is called if the mock API response is 2xx");
    }).catch(function() {
        console.log("I will be executed when flush is called if the mock API response is NOT 2xx");
    });
}
```

UNIT TEST CODE ...

```
$httpBackend.expectGET('/mypath').respond(200, {data:"fred"});
controller.callme();
// The THEN code has not been executed here
$httpBackend.flush();
// The THEN success code is now executed because we responded with 2xx (200)
```

Comment: I am using `$httpBackend.expectGET`, and `$httpBackend.flush();` in the test, but I get `Error: No pending request to flush !`. I want to know what I need to do specificly for angular-datatables to make it work.

Comment: when you call flush it is saying, for any pending requests make them now. This will trigger the code inside the $http THEN statement. If your code has not made a request at the point at which you call flush then you will get the error you are experiencing. Ensure that your code has attempted to make an http request before you call flush.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some code to illustrate. The code was written free hand so there might be syntax mistakes but you should get the idea.

Comment: Thanks, but that was already clear to me. But I want to know specificly for `angular-datatables` what I need to call in the unit test code to trigger the remote call.

Comment: ok i see the problem now. Can you not refactor your code a bit. Instead of using the fromSource method to populate the table is there not a fromJson method or something? Then populate the JSON using $http. This will make unit testing easier. Not an ideal answer! Sorry, I've never use ng-datatables. If nothing else hopefully this discussion will help someone better understand the problem.